# When and how is the Java DB updated and synced with Apache Derby?

Tags: java, database, derby, javadb

Oracle ships the JDK with "[JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html)" which is more or less a rebranded version of [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/).

Is Java DB updated and synced continually with each update release of the JDK ("_uXX") or only for major releases like Java 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Getting Started with Java DB](http://download.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/getstart/getstart-single.html) guide addresses this in the note on the [relationship between the two products](http://download.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/getstart/getstart-single.html#cgsjavadb):

> ### Relationship between Java DB and Apache Derby
>
> Java DB is a relational database management system that is based on
>   the Java programming language and SQL. Java DB is the Oracle release
>   of the Apache Derby project, the Apache Software Foundation's (ASF)
>   open source relational database project.
>
> **The Java DB product includes Derby without any modification whatsoever
>   to the underlying source code.**
>
> Because Java DB and Derby have the same functionality, the Java DB
>   documentation refers to the core functionality as Derby.
>
> **Java DB Version 10.6 is based on the Version 10.6 release of Derby.
>   References to "Derby" in the Java DB documentation refer to the
>   Version 10.6 release of Apache Derby.**

Based on the sentences being emphasized in bold, I would conclude that each version is more or less the same as the underlying Java DB version, with the version numbers also being the same (this is going by the versions listed in the Java DB downloads page).

This would not address the question on when Oracle/Sun makes a new release of Java DB. I would assume that is left to the specific team that manages the Java DB releases.